# Changing Windows Vista/7's Transparency Color

Tags: c#, winforms, transparency, aero, aero-glass

Ok, so I've heard that the color Microsoft decided to use for there Transparency is Black. Which would explain why black text is invisible when drawn/placed onto a Glass surface.

Wouldn't it just make sense for us to change the transparency color (black) BACK to Magenta? Why didn't they do this again? Is it even possible to change this color?

Comment: This belongs on superuser.com, unless you meant to ask how you can change the color *programatically*.

Comment: Obviously... That's why C# is one of the tags...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about chainging the transparent color, but you could render #010101 text and it should be dark enough for black, no? On a glass surface pure black could be hard to see anyway.

Comment: It looks very jaggered, and has a silly, ugly white border around it when I do that.